# Seeking term for calculating variables within defined distance of point?

Tags: proximity

Imagine I have a dataset where each row is a single property with information like square footage, price, the lat/lon, etc. For each row, I would like to identify all other properties within a defined radius -- for example: 0.25 miles -- then, I want to calculate new variables from within that radius (like average square footage of all properties within 0.25 miles).

My hypothesis is that calculating variables in this manner will have more predictive power than using "panel data", for example, "Median income in the census tract" or "Average square feet in the neighborhood".

Basically, I would like to show one model with panel data, and another with explanatory variables calculated from a radius around each individual point, and compare the results of the predictive models (predicting, for example, the price of the property).

What is the correct term for this procedure?

Is there any recent research comparing the use of panel data to the above-described procedure?

Comment: I'd call it proximity analysis.